# Calculating specific heat of an ideal gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

I have a more math question about calculating the heat capacity of an ideal gas undergoing a process where

$$ p = \alpha V$$

I'm currently at:

$$dQ = nC_V\cdot dT + pdV$$

But I'm confused about where to take the math from here. I know that I want the left side to end up with
$$\frac{dQ}{dT} = $$

The one path that got me a solution was to first integrate everything and then take the derivative with respect to T.

$$ Q = nC_VT+\alpha \frac{V^2}{2}$$

$$ Q = nC_VT+\frac{nrT}{2}$$

$$ \frac{dQ}{dT} = nC_V+\frac{nR}{2}$$

This answer seems unintuitive to me because it would mean that the heat capacity is not at all dependent on alpha.

But If this is not the way to go, I don't know what else to do. Do I divide everything by dT, or do I take the derivative of both sides with respect to T?

I tried divding by dT first and then trying to find dV/dT from the ideal gas law, but end up with:

$$\frac{dV}{dT} = \sqrt{\frac{nR}{\alpha}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{T}}$$

Which means I have no way to eliminate the p or the T.

If I'm supposed to take the derivative, how do I deal with the dT and the dV already on the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your first approach is correct even though it seems counter-intuitive to you that alpha has no presence or effect. You can consider this to help you, that in an isothermal process PV=constant and the heat capacity does not depend upon the constant term. Here, it is simply P/V=constant and hence, it is not any different intuitively.

That taken care of, you differentiate P/V=constant to get PdV=VdP and since you know that PdV+VdP=nRdT, you get that PdV(Work done by gas)=nRdT/2. Put this in the equation to get the specific heat you obtained in the first method that you have described in your question. So, there are two ways to the answer.